# Creating Outgoing dialer with UCMA using User Endpoint NOT Application Endpoint

Tags: c#, skype-for-business, ucma

I was trying [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/lync-2010/hh530044(v%3Doffice.14)) from Microsoft documentation link to create an outgoing dialer using UCMA 5.0. However, I want to use User Endpoint instead of Application Endpoint. Is it possible to achieve the same results by using User Endpoint, instead of using Application endpoint with UCMA?

I am using Skype for Business 2016 on the client side and UCMA SDK version is 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

UCMA can be used to create two types of applications:

1. Trusted Applications
2. User Applications

Trusted applications can use either ApplicationEndpoint's and/OR UserEndpoint's without requiring any passwords.  Trusted applications don't have to use just ApplicationEndpoint's, but the setup for a trusted application is complex.  It requires the machine that the UCMA application is run on to be "trusted" and all your certificates are correct.  Trusted applications can also do things with Endpoint's that cann't be done from a User Application.

User Applications can only use UserEndpoint's and they can be run from any machine, BUT you must provide the users password for it work.  So if you can get the user password somehow then a user application is a lot easier to setup and develop.

You can also switch between the types if you like, it's really just a setup issue only.  So you could develop/test the application as user application then which to a trusted application for deployment.

There is not a lot of difference between ApplicationEndpoint and UserEndpoint (mainly setup), they are both subclassed from "Endpoint", so yes you should be able to change from a ApplicationEndpoint to a UserEndpoint without any problems.

If you can use a "User Application" setup or a "Trusted Application" setup is another issue.  It will depend on what features the code is using.  From my brief glance at the code it doesn't look like it uses anything that a user application can't do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from the link you provided, it describes hot to create server application:

> Organizations that are using Microsoft Lync Server 2010 may decide to execute these dialing campaigns. Microsoft Unified Communications Managed API (UCMA) 3.0 makes it fairly easy to create **server applications** which can perform these tasks using Lync Server 2010.

Server applications for SfB require application endpoints. You see, user endpoint in UCMA can only provide abilities similar to regular SfB client and nothing more than that. Actually SfB client uses userendpoit under the hood. Therefore userendpoints have a lot of limitations and can not be used for non simple users taks. I suspect that nothing changes here since version 3.0.